# How can I catch the exception when I use OpenAI API client for Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, openai-api

I use [OpenAI API client](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin) for Kotlin in my Android Studio project.

I use Code A to transcribe a voice to text

1:  I don't know if  `val transcription = openAI.transcription(transcriptionRequest)` can throw  exception, could you tell me?

2:  How can I get the error informatioin when `val transcription = openAI.transcription(transcriptionRequest)` crashed ?

BTW, the Code B is source code, It returns `Transcription` class, and it seems not to throw exception.

**Code A**

```
  val apiKey = "sk-..."
    val openAI = OpenAI(apiKey)

    val transcriptionRequest = TranscriptionRequest(
        audio = FileSource(path = mInfo.soundFilename.toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
        model = ModelId("whisper-1"),
    )

   val transcription = openAI.transcription(transcriptionRequest)

    mInfo.text = transcription.text
```

**Code B**

```
  @BetaOpenAI
    public suspend fun transcription(request: TranscriptionRequest): Transcription
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`aallam/openai-kotlin` issue 131](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/issues/131), you can try and encapsulate your OpenAI code with the exceptions from the [`com.aallam.openai.api.exception`](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/tree/327b86fd7279aa8fce61fe9917dfaca57f7a99fd/openai-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/com.aallam.openai.api/exception) package:

```kotlin
val apiKey = "sk-..."
val openAI = OpenAI(apiKey)

val transcriptionRequest = TranscriptionRequest(
    audio = FileSource(path = mInfo.soundFilename.toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
    model = ModelId("whisper-1"),
)

try {
    val transcription = openAI.transcription(transcriptionRequest)
    mInfo.text = transcription.text
} catch (e: OpenAIException) {
    // Handle OpenAIExceptions
    println("OpenAIException: ${e.message}")
} catch (e: OpenAIHttpException) {
    // Handle OpenAIHttpExceptions
    println("OpenAIHttpException: ${e.message}")
} catch (e: OpenAIAPIException) {
    // Handle OpenAIAPIExceptions
    println("OpenAIAPIException: ${e.message}")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Handle any other exceptions
    println("Unexpected error: ${e.message}")
}
```

That would handle the specific exceptions `OpenAIException`, `OpenAIHttpException`, and `OpenAIAPIException` that may be thrown by the OpenAI Kotlin API client, in addition to a generic catch-all for any other exceptions.

---

Note that, if you are getting an empty error message, that would typically mean that the `Exception` itself is being thrown, but no specific message has been assigned to it.
In this case, it would appear that the OpenAI Kotlin client library is not assigning a message to the exception that it throws when the API key is invalid.

You might get more information by calling `e.toString()` instead of `e.message` in your `catch` blocks, as `toString()` typically includes both the exception class name and the message, while `e.message` only provides the message.
However, if the library does not provide a message, `e.toString()` might not provide much more information.

That would be:

```kotlin
val apiKey = "sk-..."
val openAI = OpenAI(apiKey)

val transcriptionRequest = TranscriptionRequest(
    audio = FileSource(path = mInfo.soundFilename.toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
    model = ModelId("whisper-1"),
)

try {
    val transcription = openAI.transcription(transcriptionRequest)
    mInfo.text = transcription.text
} catch (e: OpenAIException) {
    // Handle OpenAIExceptions
    println("OpenAIException: ${e.toString()}")
} catch (e: OpenAIHttpException) {
    // Handle OpenAIHttpExceptions
    println("OpenAIHttpException: ${e.toString()}")
} catch (e: OpenAIAPIException) {
    // Handle OpenAIAPIExceptions
    println("OpenAIAPIException: ${e.toString()}")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Handle any other exceptions
    println("Unexpected error: ${e.toString()}")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the string of `e.message` defined by OpenAI API? or by com.aallam.openai:openai-client package? where can I find the details of these string of error message?  such as string :  `Connect timeout has expired.  ...`

Comment: @HelloCW If you look at your exception callstack, you should see `Caused by: io.ktor.client.network.sockets.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect timeout has expired [url=https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions, connect_timeout=unknown ms]`. Which means the messages are not defined by OpenAI API, buy wrapped by OpenAI's custom error type. [This one comes from here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/8a2ce42e7300c912fc6ed922f98cb803e1a74c0f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/plugins/HttpTimeout.kt#L213-L215).

Comment: Thanks!  If I use a wrong OpenAI api Key ,  it seems that I get a empty error message with your code.

Comment: @HelloCW But you do catch en error?

Comment: Yes,  I do catch en error catch using your code, but I get an empty error message  if I provide a wrong API key to launch the funtion `TranscriptionRequest()`'.